# distinct several services nodejs with ps aux | grep node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have 6 services nodejs  running in one server. Sometimes I need to kill one of them, but when I execute:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

All the 6 services appears with the same name. I dont know which one of them to kill.

There are some way to diff. them?

Comment: You may want to look into https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`PM2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to manage your nodejs applications. It can also help you in restarting the node process once server is rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the port of your services and linux, this could help:

sudo netstat -tulpn